# Java FileInputStream in a Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans-7, fileinputstream

I have a little problem, i'm trying to load a properties file with a FileInputStream in a Java Web Service.

The app.config.properties file contains the next line:

```
fileSales = C:/Users/clens/Documents/sales.xml
```

My java web service class contains the next lines:

```
    InputStream is = null;
    try 
    {
      is = new FileInputStream("app.config.properties");
      objPropiedades.load(is);
      ruta = objPropiedades.getProperty("fileSales");
    } 
    catch(IOException ioe) 
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The console show me the next exception:

```
FileNotFoundException: app.config.properties
```

The log file:

> ```
> SEVERE:   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
> SEVERE:   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
> SEVERE:   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
> ```

Comment: It looks like you've posted half a stack trace. What is the actual exception?

Comment: @DuncanJones The app.confi.properties exists but the web service can't find the file

Comment: The path you've supplied to the `FileInputStream` constructor is not valid unless it's in your current working directory. It probably isn't.

Comment: Where is `app.config.properties` located, relative to your web application?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the app.config.properties exists in the path C:\Users\clens\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FranquiciaWS 

The path of my java class is: C:\Users\clens\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FranquiciaWS\src\java\Model

Comment: You should not put properties files in your project root directory. They should be on the classpath so regardless of how you run your application, they will be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your properties file is certainly in your classpath, use this code to get an `InputStream`to it :

```
is = MyService.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/app.config.properties");
```

Adapt the path to the package that is containing the file (with dots replaced by slashes).

Comment: the app.config.properties exists in the path C:\Users\clens\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FranquiciaWS The path of my java class is: C:\Users\clens\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FranquiciaWS\src\java\Model

Comment: so also move your file to `C:\Users\clens\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FranquiciaWS\src\java` or `C:\Users\clens\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FranquiciaWS\src\resources`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your app.config.properties file is not at your work location.

Two options

1. Place the app.config.properties file in your WEB-INF/classes/ folder
   of the web services app.
2. Refer the app.config.properties file with a
   full qualified path name. Assuming that this is a standard web service application.

   E:\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\WebServiceProject\WEB-INF\classes\app.config.properties